# the position changing problem for multi-slides

Tags: beamer, slideshow

I have one problem with multi-slides. as you see below, I define some columns and "onlyenv". I put some minipages in this columns for organizing them into my language package. This type of slides is good for me. But when I change the multi-slides in slides, the position of my minipage contents changes. While my contents in multi-slides are the same. How can it be solved? the MWE code is as below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

 \usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{tuelightblue}{cmyk}{0.2, 0.15, 0.04,  0.0}
\definecolor{tueblue}{cmyk}{1.0, 0.93, 0.18, 0.05}
\definecolor{tuepurple}{cmyk}{0.14, 0.97, 0.51, 0.01}
\definecolor{babypink}{rgb}{0.96, 0.76, 0.76}


\tikzset{onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
  \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
}}
\begin{document}
\section{first}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
 \vrule{}
    \begin{onlyenv}<1>
        \begin{column}{.85\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
text here
\end{minipage}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.475\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{dimpprot10000.pdf}
  \caption{reynolds 5000}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.475\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{dimpprot10000.pdf}
  \caption{reynolds 10000}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure} 
\end{column}  
    \end{onlyenv}
    \begin{onlyenv}<2>
        \begin{column}{.85\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
text here
 \end{minipage}
     \begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.475\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{dimpprot10000.pdf}
  \caption{reynolds 5000}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.475\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{dimpprot10000.pdf}
  \caption{reynolds 10000}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{column}   
    \end{onlyenv}   
    \begin{onlyenv}<3>
    \begin{column}{.85\textwidth}
    \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
 text here
 \end{minipage}
      \begin{figure}
 \begin{minipage}{.475\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{dimpprot10000.pdf}
  \caption{reynolds 5000}
 \end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.475\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{dimpprot10000.pdf}
  \caption{reynolds 10000}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure} 
\end{column}
    \end{onlyenv}
       \vrule{}
    \begin{column}{.15\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[onslide=<1>{fill=tuepurple},onslide=    <2->{fill=tuelightblue},circle,text width=0.5cm,align=center,inner     sep=1pt,minimum size=1.3cm]{\footnotesize{text one}};
         \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[onslide=<2>{fill=tuepurple},onslide=    <1>{fill=tuelightblue},onslide=<3>{fill=tuelightblue},circle,text     width=0.5cm,align=center,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=1.3cm]    {\footnotesize{text two}};
        \end{tikzpicture}       
       \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[onslide=<3>{fill=tuepurple},onslide=<-2>{fill=tuelightblue},circle,text width=0.5cm,align=center,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=1.3cm]{\footnotesize{text three}};
        \end{tikzpicture}  
    \end{center}  
    \end{column}
     \vrule{}
 \end{columns}

 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: I am afraid, I don't understand the question. Can you maybe add a picture and mark what should be changed?

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Carter. the following images are attached for saying my problem. If you compare the images, we have a horizontal shift between images to the right side. This shift is obvious in the text. by the way, if you run the above code, you find it better.

![slide1](https://imgur.com/a/4KVhU)
![slide2](https://imgur.com/a/tHUEP)
![slide3](https://imgur.com/a/NW7J0)

Comment: Oh, I think I now understand the question! BTW please don't call me Mr.  :)

Answer (score 1):

- to fix the problem with the horizontal alignment, change the order of `column` and `onlyenv`
- `xcolor` is not necessary with beamer
- `\footnotesize` is a switch and does not take arguments. This means `\footnotesize{bla}` should be `{\footnotesize bla}`

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

% \usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{tuelightblue}{cmyk}{0.2, 0.15, 0.04,  0.0}
\definecolor{tueblue}{cmyk}{1.0, 0.93, 0.18, 0.05}
\definecolor{tuepurple}{cmyk}{0.14, 0.97, 0.51, 0.01}
\definecolor{babypink}{rgb}{0.96, 0.76, 0.76}

\tikzset{onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
\only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
}}

\begin{document}

\section{first}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \vrule{}%
        \begin{column}{.85\textwidth}%
            \begin{onlyenv}<1>%
                \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}%
                    text here%
                \end{minipage}%
                \begin{figure}%
                    \begin{minipage}{.475\textwidth}%
                        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}%
                        \caption{reynolds 5000}%
                    \end{minipage}%
                    \begin{minipage}{.475\textwidth}%
                        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}%
                        \caption{reynolds 10000}%
                    \end{minipage}%
                \end{figure}%
            \end{onlyenv}%
            \begin{onlyenv}<2>%
                \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}%
                    text here%
                \end{minipage}%
                \begin{figure}%
                    \begin{minipage}{.475\textwidth}%
                        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}%
                        \caption{reynolds 5000}%
                    \end{minipage}%
                    \begin{minipage}{.475\textwidth}%
                        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}%
                        \caption{reynolds 10000}%
                    \end{minipage}%
                \end{figure}%
            \end{onlyenv}%          
            \begin{onlyenv}<3>%
                \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}%
                    text here%
                \end{minipage}%
                \begin{figure}%
                    \begin{minipage}{.475\textwidth}%
                        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}%
                        \caption{reynolds 5000}%
                    \end{minipage}%
                    \begin{minipage}{.475\textwidth}%
                        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}%
                        \caption{reynolds 10000}%
                    \end{minipage}%
                \end{figure}%
            \end{onlyenv}%
        \end{column}
        \vrule{}
        \begin{column}{.15\textwidth}
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \node[onslide=<1>{fill=tuepurple},onslide=    <2->{fill=tuelightblue},circle,text width=0.5cm,align=center,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=1.3cm]{\footnotesize text one};
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \node[onslide=<2>{fill=tuepurple},onslide=    <1>{fill=tuelightblue},onslide=<3>{fill=tuelightblue},circle,text width=0.5cm,align=center,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=1.3cm] {\footnotesize text two};
                \end{tikzpicture}       
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \node[onslide=<3>{fill=tuepurple},onslide=<-2>{fill=tuelightblue},circle,text width=0.5cm,align=center,inner sep=1pt,minimum size=1.3cm]{\footnotesize text three};
                \end{tikzpicture}  
            \end{center}  
        \end{column}
        \vrule{}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @mohammadfazli You're welcome!

Comment: excuse me, I edit mine comment.